# Using Where and or with two attributes in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I would like to use a scope function and make the query so that it applies the scopes, and apply either of two conditions:

I was looking for something like this:

```
apply_scopes(Message).where((user_id: current_user.id) || (recipient_id: current_user.id))
```

but it has a syntax error obviously.

When is use:

```
apply_scopes(Message).where(user_id: current_user.id).or(Message.where(recipient_id: current_user.id))
```

i am under the impression that the scope is not taken in account.

What is the proper way of using `WHERE` and `OR` with two variable please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to be careful when using `Model.or`. OR in SQL has lower precedence than AND so you can get surprising results. For example, suppose there's a scope `some_scope` that includes results with `id = 6` but not those with `id = 11`, then this:

```
Model.some_scope.where(id: 6).or(Model.where(id: 11))
```

will produce SQL like this:

```
select * from models where some_scope and id = 6 or id = 11
```

and adding parentheses to hilight the precedence:

```
select * from models where (some_scope and id = 6) or id = 11
```

and we find that the query finds both `6` and `11`.

But if we apply the scope at the end:

```
Model.where(id: 6).or(Model.where(id: 11)).some_scope
```

we get SQL like this:

```
select * from models where (id = 6 or id = 11) and some_scope
```

and only `6` is found.

I'd probably go with a string condition and a named placeholder:

```
apply_scopes(Message).where('messages.user_id = :uid or messages.recipient_id = :uid', uid: current_user.id)
```

to avoid confusion. In this particular case, you could also add another scope to `Message` if you want to hide the string:

```
scope :involving, ->(user) { where('messages.user_id = :uid or messages.recipient_id = :uid', uid: user) }
```

Presumably you'll be doing a lot of this sort of thing so an extra scope makes sense.

Comment: This is very educative, thank you very much. I will have to review a few sections of the project then.

Comment: You're welcome. The `to_sql` method can be invaluable when working with ActiveRecord, things like `Model.where(...).some_scope.to_sql`.